# Getting this json data and displaying it

Tags: jquery, json

I have this JSON in my php, how can I loop through it using jQuery and display the contents?

```
$data = array(
(object)array(
    'oV' => 'myfirstvalue',
    'oT' => 'myfirsttext',
),
(object)array(
    'oV' => 'mysecondvalue',
    'oT' => 'mysecondtext',
),
);
```

NEW CODE VARIATION:

```
for($d=0;$d<4;$d++){
  $data = array(
(object)array(
    'oV' => myfirstvalue[d],
    'oT' => myfirsttext[d],
),
);
}
```

Comment: what is your json?  Have tried looping your json?

Answer (score 1):

json encoding your array

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

would produce

```
[
  {
     "oV":"myfirstvalue",
     "oT":"myfirsttext"
  },
  {
     "oV":"mysecondvalue",
     "oT":"mysecondtext"
  }
]
```

which should be the json response you want to echo back as the ajax response.

so to loop over this json response in javascript, do like

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {

    console.log(data[i].oV,data[i].oT); 

}
```

Comment: can you get me a jquery variation

Comment: how about getting a jquery sample ,please

Comment: the way to loop over an array in javascript wont change in jquery. Its just a library on top of javascript.

Comment: cant you check the same by trying out?

Comment: I have seen where the problem was.the loop has to be inside where the oV = is or oN = is